# OS X key event in menu bar app (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been working on a Cocoa project recently. It's a menu bar/status bar-only application. I need some extra information to appear in the menu bar app when the user holds down the option key, and I've been looking everywhere to see how this is possible without any windows showing onscreen. Is it possible to run `keyDown:` from AppDelegate.swift to do this? Guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: addGlobalEventMonitoring for flags changed

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain a little bit more with some example code? Sorry, I'm a noob at Swift in Cocoa apps.

Comment: Monitor globally the option key ?

Comment: @LeoDabus I only want the extra content in my menu bar app to appear if I hold down option then click my app in the OS X menu bar. I don't want it to happen if I don't do that.

Comment: Do you still need help identifying the keys?

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, your solution isn't exactly what I was looking for. I only want the information to show if I press it right before I click the app in the OS X menu bar. Then, after I click away from my app and it goes away, I want it to remove itself, etc. I know this is possible since I've seen it with other OS X menu bar apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can monitor the key down globally but the option key you can do as follow:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.FlagsChangedMask) { (theEvent) -> Void in
    if theEvent.modifierFlags.intersect(.DeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask) == .AlternateKeyMask {
        print("ONLY OPTION")
    }
    switch theEvent.modifierFlags.intersect(.DeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask) {
    case NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask :
        print("shift key is pressed")
    case NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask:
        print("control key is pressed")
    case NSEventModifierFlags.AlternateKeyMask :
        print("option key is pressed")
    case NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask:
        print("Command key is pressed")
    default:
        print("no key or more than one is pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work if the user has the menu open...this only works if the user clisk on the key prior to navigating the menu

Comment: This also would work if you add a bool for the key you would like to monitor and just flag it on/off

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean change menu item when user hold the option key?

Checkout `isAlternate` and `keyEquivalentModifierMask` properties of menu item.

Also [Option (⌥) + Context Menu in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764644/option-context-menu-in-cocoa)