# How to handle keydown event? | Swift3 OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, event-handling, swift3, macos-sierra

Is it possible for a background application to know when a key is pressed on the keyboard?

It doesn't matter which key I don't need to differentiate, and the app would be allowed in inaccessibility.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34562563/2303865

Answer (score 0):

declare an event monitor like

```
var eventMonitor: Any?
```

in your viewDidLoad() method Start monitorng like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Start monitoring
        eventMonitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, 
        handler: onEvent)
}
```

And the handler method will be look ilke

```
func onEvent(_ incomingEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("KeyPressed \(incomingEvent.characters!)")
}
```

You wanted to enable accessibility for Your app in order to get key press events. the following code will show a pop for user requesting the accessibilt.

```
let options : NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeRetainedValue() as NSString: true]
```