# How to detect Option key down in Status bar app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I have a `Swift Cocoa` app that runs as an `NSStatusItem`, i.e., it presents a dropdown menu in Mac's top-right status bar. I would like to display extra "advanced" menu items when the user holds down the Option key while opening my status item menu. I can detect presses of the Option key, but my problem is that I cannot determine whether the key is down or up.

Here is the code I have so far in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
  NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.flagsChanged, handler: keyEvent);
}
    
func keyEvent(event: NSEvent) {
  if let event = NSApp.currentEvent {
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) {
      print("option key up/down event")
    }
  }
}
```

This works insofar as it prints the message when the Option key is either pressed down or released back up. The problem is that I don't know how to determine which state the Option key is in at any given time.

How can I adapt this code to know if the Option key is down or up?

**EDIT**:  SO suggested that I edit my question to explain why it is not answered by [Hide/Show menu item in application's main menu by pressing Option key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208632/hide-show-menu-item-in-applications-main-menu-by-pressing-option-key).  Briefly, the answers on that page, while probably workable, seemed either overly complex (adding timers, adding run loop observers, adding zero height custom views) or they were creating menu item [alternates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514823-isalternate) whereas I was trying to add *additional* menu items. Nevertheless, it is a good page and I recommend studying it if you also have this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Show menu item in application's main menu by pressing Option key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208632/hide-show-menu-item-in-applications-main-menu-by-pressing-option-key)

Comment: I did come across this one in my research.  The asker states that he tried `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` and `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` and did not get any events, whereas I do get events using the latter NSEvent method.  Maybe this answer is the right approach anyway, though; how would I translate it into Swift and the AppDelegate model?

Comment: You don't need to monitor events. Do you want to change menu items when the Option-key is down or do you want to add extra menu items?

Comment: In ObjC you can just use `NSEvent.modifierFlags` (property on the class), chances are that works in Swift as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just ask for the current event and return a `Bool`, it's `true` when the key is pressed at the moment

```
func isOptionKeyPressed() -> Bool {
    return NSEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.option)
}
```

`addGlobalMonitorForEvents` is not needed

Comment: Where would I call this code from?  I am already calling `NSEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.option)` in the code I posted with the original question.  Now, you are also saying to eliminate `addGlobalMonitorForEvents`, which implies eliminating the `keyEvent()` method in the code I posted, but in that case I am not sure where I would call your code from.  I tried calling it in my `NSMenuDelegate`'s `menuWillOpen` to decide how to set the `.isHidden` property on the "extra" menu item, but holding down Option had no effect when I put the code there.  Can you expand the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a working solution, inspired by (but not the same as) another answer here posted by vadian.  This is my solution.

1. Eliminate the `addGlobalMonitorForEvents` and `keyEvent` code in my original question.
2. Create an an NSMenuDelegate like so:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var extrasSeparator: NSMenuItem?
    @IBOutlet weak var extrasSubmenu: NSMenuItem?

    [...rest of AppDelegate...]
}

extension AppDelegate: NSMenuDelegate {
    func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        if NSEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.option) {
            extrasSeparator?.isHidden = false
            extrasSubmenu?.isHidden = false
        } else {
            extrasSeparator?.isHidden = true
            extrasSubmenu?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat:  this solution only works if the user presses and holds the Option key *before* clicking the NSStatusItem's icon.  That's what was asked in the original question, but it may not be desirable in all cases.